# Get details of icons and files present on desktop with there location on desktop?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I there a way to read/query the details of desktop on OSX. I want to fetch the information like Files & Folder visible on desktop with there position?

I think I can use following api from the NSFileManger and it can give files and folder.

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask error:(NSError **)error
```

But I also need desktop files position and there corresponding icons. Can anyone help me or suggest some ideas?

Answer (score -1):

For icon you can use

```
[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:filePath];
```

you can use `AppleScript` for position of desktop items.

```
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    get the name of every item of desktop
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    get the position of every item of the desktop
```